# Apache Wicket - Form not being submitted

Tags: java, html, forms, apache, wicket

Simple, I click on the input that has the `type="submit"`, and the form isn't submitted.

I've searched solutions to this issue but they say I should check if I have nested forms, which I don't, I'm only using one. They also said it could be some misplaced tag, but I've gone through the whole HTML and the tags are fine.

I have this block in the HTML:

```
<div id="form-options-div" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" wicket:id="saveClientButton" id="save-client-button" />
    <input class="btn" type="button" id="close-client-button" wicket:id="closeClientButton"/>
</div>
```

I'm using an `AjaxButton` in the java code to represent the `saveClientButton`.

I'm overriding the `onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget, Form<?>)`. I would post the whole java code, but I have a logger at the start of the method to see if it's being called:

`logger.debug("ON SUBMIT");`

So it's not inside the method. An interesting thing is that when I override the Form `onSubmit()` method, instead of the AjaxButton one, the page actually reloads. But it's only that, the onSubmit method still isn't called.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

`private Button saveClientBtn;`

```
saveClientBtn = new AjaxButton(WICKET_ID_SAVE_CLIENT_BUTTON) {

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            logger.debug("Error on submit...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
           //code....
        }
};
```

Could the `closeClientButton` be interfering with the normal behavior? I don't know, because the button type is `button`, not `submit`.

`editClientForm = new Form<Client>(WICKET_ID_EDIT_CLIENT_FORM);`

`add(editClientForm);`

`editClientForm.add(saveClientBtn);`

EDIT 2:

OK, instead of using AjaxButton, I decided to override the Form `onSubmit()` and `onError()`. When clicking the button, I see that `onError()` is called. Now I need to find the reason why.

Ok, I put a FeedbackPanel. It gives me the following message:

`'[Page class = EditClientPage, id = 6, render count = 1]' is not a valid EditClientPage.`

Also, the error appears 4 times, as in:

`'[Page class = EditClientPage, id = 6, render count = 1]' is not a valid EditClientPage.`

`'[Page class = EditClientPage, id = 6, render count = 1]' is not a valid EditClientPage.`

`'[Page class = EditClientPage, id = 6, render count = 1]' is not a valid EditClientPage.`

`'[Page class = EditClientPage, id = 6, render count = 1]' is not a valid EditClientPage.`

What does this error means?

Comment: have you Overriden the onError() on the Button to see if you reach it? BTW, Wicket handles nested forms (which are not allowed in HTML) via subsituting the inner form with a div.

Comment: @bert I tried overriding and putting a log... but it is not called. Also I double checked, no nested form. I'm going crazy over this issue... I hope it's not something dumb and I just can't see it.

Comment: Did you add a FeedbackPanel?

Comment: Unless you have your markup embedded in a `<form>` tag, Wicket can't submit the form.

Comment: @svenmeier I did not add a FeedbackPanel.

Comment: @MartijnDashorst Can you give me an example? Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a form tag.

e.g.:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form wicket:id="form">
       <div wicket:id="registration">
          Display the RegistrationInputPanel
       </div>
       <input type=”submit” wicket:id="register" value="Register"/>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the java class:

```
public class RegistrationPage extends Page {
    public RegistrationPage(IModel<Registration> regModel) {
        Form<?> form = new Form("form");
        form.add(new RegistrationInputPanel("registration", regModel);
        form.add(new SubmitButton("register") {
            public void onSubmit() {

            }
        });
        add(form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it appears I was not setting a "required" value within the form.

This was ascertained by adding an "onError" method to the form object (sure enough, onError was being called, you can tell "what" the error [was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982575/32453) like

`String responseTxt = wicketTester.getLastResponse().getDocument();`

And dig through it to look for the error message.

To actually set the value, in my case, was

```
FormTester formTester = wicketTester.newFormTester("formName");
formTester.setValue("requiredElementName", "value");
```

Then the `onSubmit` method started being called within tests, as was expected.